# Flash - playing video

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, embed, flowplayer

I'm developing a Flash-only application and I want to integrate the `flowplayer` directly into it, but not on the webpage using some `swfobject`-like approach.

So, at some moment (for example, when arbitrary event fires), I would like to add the `flowplayer` object to the scene so that it starts streaming the specified video.

**Does someone know if that is possible?**

*Would the following API (http://releases.flowplayer.org/apidoc-latest/index.html) help me somehow?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this http://flowplayer.org/forum/1/37338